# Simple table sort with three columns - keeping track of column and order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three table headers, each with ID's: **deadline_column**, **duration_column**, and **description_column**

Each `<th>` has an class of 'headerSort'. What I'm trying to do right now is, once one of the headings are clicked: determine the column clicked, and then alternate between ascending and descending. The main trouble I'm having is going back to the default sort (ascending) when a new column is clicked. Right now I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var order;
            var column; 

            $('.headerSort').on('click', function(){
                var column = $(this).attr('id');
                if (order=='ascending'){
                    order = 'descending';
                } else {
                    order = 'ascending'; 
                }

                alert (order);
                // deadline_column
                // duration_column
                // description_column

                // switch(column){
                //  case 'deadline_column':
                //  break;

                //  case 'duration_column':
                //  break;

                //  case 'description_column':
                //  break;
                // }

            });
```

I can't think up a way to do this that won't come out being overly verbose.

Comment: You can try using a simple plugin to do that for you.  Tablesorter is a lightweight jquery plugin that can take of that http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm trying to do this without any plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var order;
        var column; 

        $('.headerSort').on('click', function(){
            var newColumn = $(this).attr('id');
            if(column !== newColumn){
                column = newColumn;
                order = 'ascending';
            }
            else{
                if (order=='ascending'){
                    order = 'descending';
                } else {
                    order = 'ascending'; 
                }
            }

            alert (order);
        });
});
```